# iOS: Maintain pointer to UI element

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface

I'm constructing a UI on iOS that is pretty extensive, and I need to update some passive components (i.e. the user doesn't interact with them, but their values will change from time to time). I was hoping to avoid looping over all elements in my UI by maintaining a dictionary with the pointer to the UI element in question as the value:

In My UI construction function:

```
if (creating)
{
   // add this to our list of computed parameters as well, for refresh purposes
   NSString* internalName = [[parameter objectForKey:@"internalName"] description];
   currUIControl.fParamInternalName = internalName;
   [self.fComputedParametersInPlan setObject:currUIControl forKey:internalName];
}
```

Where:
- self.fComputedParametersInPlan is a class level dictionary
- currUIControl is a pointer of some UI type (Foo*, say)
- internalName is the key I'll be using

The problem is that when I go out of scope (i.e. out of the creation function), the pointer values for the dictionary entries go to NULL, so when I query them somewhere else in my code, I get nil back:

```
Foo* paramCtrl = [self.fComputedParametersInPlan objectForKey:internalName];
```

Any ideas on how I can preserve the pointers? Or of having some way of grabbing the object when I need it?

Comment: You said *"when I go out of scope"*. What is "I" in that statement?

Comment: You need to show more code. A dictionary will hold a strong reference to its values, so something else is going on here

Comment: Did you ever actually alloc/init `self.fComputedParametersInPlan`?

Comment: Yes i did. Still doesn't work.

Comment: What does "class level dictionary" mean? An instance variable of your view controller? Is it defined as strong? weak? unsafe_unretained? Post the code that defines all the variables you show in your code. Also, what do you mean "the pointer values for the dictionary entries go to NULL"? Does the dictionary get released? Show code or describe the debugging steps you are using to conclude that your data "go[es] to NULL"

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to preserve references to UI* elements is to hook them up to a member in the owning `ViewController` using an `IBOutlet`.

[Here's the relevant Apple documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Outlets/Outlets.html)

[Any here's a tutorial from Apple to get you started.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/DefiningtheInteraction.html)

Comment: In this case, it's a variable number of elements, I'm not sure if it's a good idea to create a lot of IBOutlets.

Comment: @user1115716 : In this case, you can use an IBOutletCollection if they're related. Otherwise, I wouldn't worry about making too many outlets unless you making dozens of them.